# How to Properly Unwrap Metaball, Metaball animation

Tags: texturing, uv, animation-nodes, baking, meta-objects

I have a Metaball animation running with animation node. I want to project the UVs from the surrounding sphere to the metaballs so I can have the textures applied without artifacts (you can se in the gif). The only problem is that I don’t really know hot to do it. If it was a normal mesh I would go for the uv projection modifier, but since is a metaball I can’t apply modifiers.

Does anyone know how to solve this problem?
Thanks a lot
[image: ll]

Comment: Use the generated or object coordinates with the image texture projection mode set to Box, and the blend to a value > 0

Answer (score 1):

You can use **equirectangular** type of texture image.
Trick to apply this texture is used **Environment** texture node (instead of Image node) in material node tree.

[image]
[image]

If you don't have yet this type of texture, its very easy to let blender render one from sphere.
Let me know if you need more info.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[image: Setting up UV Projection from Mesh]

I did it this way and it worked fine for me (but i am using a cube instead of a sphere).

Under - Texture Coordinates - Object - Try to plug in your outer sphere.

Comment: What I tried it still produce visible seams to me (even with blend). Unmissable even more in animation, because projected box edges moves but texture doesnt for its projection. And I dont speak about wire texture, I tried it with crazy bark texture.